# Why does the :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac error occur when building in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli
npx react-native init temp
```

I created a project with .
And when you try to build on Android through npm start, the following error occurs.

Why does this error occur? How should I solve this?

```
info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 




  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/temp/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-33/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/21/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/temp/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6b3d3c605b53d101dbdb1344c7ea69b0/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/temp/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6b3d3c605b53d101dbdb1344c7ea69b0/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```